# How to access original collection and bind to context while iterating over an array?

Tags: javascript, collections, closures, bind, each

In this exercise, we're asked to write a function that replicates the behaviour of `_.each` (UnderscoreJS) and that passes a series of unit tests.

```
// COLLECTIONS
// _.each(collection, iteratee, [context]) 
// Iterates over a collection of elements (i.e. array or object), 
// yielding each in turn to an iteratee function, that is called with three arguments:(element, index|key, collection), and bound to the context if one is passed. 
// Returns the collection for chaining.
```

These are the unit tests it should pass (and its current status as per the code block below):

:x: - should iterate over an array

√   - should iterate over an object

√   - should ignore object prototype

:x: - should access the original collection

:x: - should bind to context if one is passed

√   - should return the collection

While I already tried several different methods(for loop, for...of), none has worked so far in successfully iterating over an array.

I also tried to implement two if statements - for the case the collection is an Array or an Object using either the `Array.isArray()` method, but also the `Object.prototype.toString.call()` to evaluate if the matches either `'[object Object]'` or `'[object Array]'`.

I wrote different variations using if-else statements, switch case and simple if statements. This is where I currently stand. I imagine that I might not be correctly referring to the context, so any hints or remarks would be highly appreciated.

**Edit** *and taking in account @Bergi's comment*:

> *"It should be iteratee.call(context, elem, index, collection) instead of iteratee.call(context, index, elem, collection); otherwise this looks fine"*

It turns out this was actually correct, and the problem was due to a mutation in the mocks data from a previous exercise. Thank you both for your input and time spent on this. Cheers!

```
_.each = function (collection, iteratee, context) {
  iteratee = iteratee.bind(context);

  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (let [index, elem] of collection.entries()) {
      iteratee.call(context, elem, index, collection);
    }
  }
  
  if (!Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for ( let el in collection) {
      if (collection.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
        iteratee.call(context, collection[el], el, collection);
      }
    }
  }
  return collection;
};
```

Comment: `iteratee = iteratee.bind(context);` is not needed since the OP already does `iteratee.call` within the `context`.

Comment: And in case `collection` is an array one could use the native [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like e.g. `collection.forEach((elm, idx) => iteratee.call(context, elm, idx, collection));` or `collection.forEach(function (elm, idx, arr) { iteratee.call(this, elm, idx, arr); }, context);`

Comment: The non array clause should be a simple `... } else { ...` where one would utilize and iterate over [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) like e.g. `Object.entries(collection).forEach(([key, value]) => iteratee.call(context, value, key, collection);`

Comment: It should be `iteratee.call(context, elem, index, collection)` instead of `iteratee.call(context, index, elem, collection)`; otherwise this looks fine

Comment: Thank you. We're not supposed to use the native `forEach` :) What puzzles me is that even with fewer redundancies, it doesn't pass the test of iterating over an array.

Comment: @licvdom ... From the so far sole answer / solution are there any questions left?

Comment: Hi Peter! No further questions. Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... We're not supposed to use the native forEach :) What puzzles me is that even with fewer redundancies, it doesn't pass the test of iterating over an array."* – licvdom

***Edit*** ... and taking into account **Bergi**'s comment ...

> *"Object.entries does not produce numbers for array indices. Don't use it on arrays."* – Bergi

One can choose a generic approach which enables the iteration of both objects (key and value) and list like structures (index and item) like `Array`s, `HTMLCollection`s, `NodeList`s or even `String`s.

A list like structure can be successfully converted into an array. The custom `each` functionality for such an array gets implemented by a simple [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Any other data structure will be passed to [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). The return value then can be iterated with a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement where the currently processed entry can be destructured into `[key, value]`.

```js
function isString(value) {
  return (/\[object\s+String\]/)
    .test(
      Object.prototype.toString.call(value)
    );
}

const _ = {
  each(possiblyIterable, iteratee, target) {

    if (typeof iteratee !== 'function') {
      throw new ReferenceError('2nd argument needs to be a function type');
    }
    // returns an array for any array or any
    // list like structures like `String`s
    // `NodeList`s or `HTMLCollection`s.
    const arr = Array.from(possiblyIterable ?? []);
    const isListLike = (arr.length >= 1);

    // assure a context or the null value.
    target = target ?? null;

    if (isListLike) {
      // requirement: "should access the original collection"
      // - tricky due to implemented list like string iteration,
      //   but solvable.
      const list = isString(possiblyIterable) ? arr : possiblyIterable;

      for (let idx = 0; idx < arr.length; ++idx) {

        iteratee.call(target, arr[idx], idx, list);
      }
    } else {
      const entries = Object.entries(possiblyIterable ?? {})
      for (let [key, value] of entries) {

        iteratee.call(target, value, key, possiblyIterable);
      }
    }
    return possiblyIterable;
  },
};


const object = { x: 'XX', y: 'YY' };
const array = [5, 3, 1];
const nodeList = document.body.querySelectorAll('em');
const string = 'test';


console.log('+++ object test ...function expression and bound target +++');
_.each(object, function (value, key, obj) {

  const target = this;
  console.log({ target, value, key, obj });

}, { foo: 'FOO' });

console.log('\n+++ array test ...function expression and bound target +++');
_.each(array, function (item, idx, list) {

  const target = this;
  console.log({ target, item, idx, list });

}, { foo: 'FOO' });

console.log('\n+++ nodeList test ...non bindable arrow function +++');
_.each(nodeList, (item, idx, list) =>

  console.log({ item, idx, list })
);

console.log('\n+++ string test ...non bindable arrow function +++');
_.each(string, (item, idx, list) =>

  console.log({ item, idx, list })
);

console.log('\n+++ return value test +++');
console.log(
  '(_.each(object, (x) => x) === object) ?..',
  (_.each(object, (x) => x) === object)
);
console.log(
  '(_.each(array, (x) => x) === array) ?..',
  (_.each(array, (x) => x) === array)
);
console.log(
  '(_.each(nodeList, (x) => x) === nodeList) ?..',
  (_.each(nodeList, (x) => x) === nodeList)
);
console.log(
  '(_.each(string, (x) => x) === string) ?..',
  (_.each(string, (x) => x) === string)
);

console.log('\n+++ 2nd argument function type test +++');
_.each(object, null);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<em>Node</em><em>List</em><em>Test</em>
```

Comment: `Object.entries` does not produce numbers for array indices. Don't use it on arrays.

Comment: @Bergi ... Thanks for noticing, I just saw it with my own tests too. Already working on fixing it.